# How do I configure VS 2022 with .NET Framework 6.0?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've searched the interwebs for a solution to this to no avail. I cannot for the life of me discover how to make a .NET 6.0 project in VS 2022. The weird part is when I go to the installer, the runtime for 6.0 is selected as installed. I cannot find an SDK option in the installer's list of packages however. I have installed the SDK for 6.0 and it shows as present when I check "dotnet --info." However, whenever I go to VS to create a project the latest version of .NET listed is 4.8.

Thanks!!

Comment: There is no `.NET Framework 6.0` and never will be one. `.Net 6` (evolution of `.Net Core`) exists and you can select it. -- If you built a Project that targets .Net Framework, the most recent (and last) version is `4.8`.

Answer (score 0):

the project you build is targeting . Net Framework, which latest version is 4.8. For the .Net 6 you mentioned is more likely .Net Core6.0. Please refer to the related link:[.Net Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about .NET6.0, .NET7.0 or ,NET8.0, the thing I did was right click on the solution's name in the Solution Explorer.  Then I selected "Upgrade" from the list.  That'll give you a list of .NET versions to upgrade to.  It worked for me.